# Handle decimal in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, fixed-point

I'm trying to find a way to handle decimals in mongodb. Is there any good way and/or should I handle it with a class like this:

```
using System;

public class MongoDecimal
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
    public long SubValue { get; set; }
    public long SubValueToValue { get; set; }

    public decimal ToDecimal()
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(Value) + (Convert.ToDecimal(SubValue) / Convert.ToDecimal(SubValueToValue));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToDecimal().ToString();
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ToDecimal().ToString(provider);
    }

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return ToDecimal().ToString(format);
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ToDecimal().ToString(format, provider);
    }

    public static MongoDecimal ToMongoDecimal(decimal value)
    {
        const long subValueToValue = 100000000;
        return ToMongoDecimal(value, subValueToValue);
    }

    public static MongoDecimal ToMongoDecimal(decimal value, long subValueToValue)
    {
        var major = Math.Truncate(value);
        var minor = Math.Truncate((value - major) * Convert.ToDecimal(subValueToValue));

        return new MongoDecimal
        {
            Value = Convert.ToInt64(major),
            SubValue = Convert.ToInt64(minor),
            SubValueToValue = subValueToValue
        };
    }

    public static MongoDecimal operator +(MongoDecimal value, MongoDecimal value2)
    {
        var right = SafeDecimal(value);
        var left = SafeDecimal(value2);

        return ToMongoDecimal(left.ToDecimal() + right.ToDecimal(), left.SubValueToValue >= right.SubValueToValue ? left.SubValueToValue : right.SubValueToValue);
    }

    public static MongoDecimal operator -(MongoDecimal value, MongoDecimal value2)
    {
        var right = SafeDecimal(value);
        var left = SafeDecimal(value2);

        return ToMongoDecimal(left.ToDecimal() - right.ToDecimal(), left.SubValueToValue >= right.SubValueToValue ? left.SubValueToValue : right.SubValueToValue);

    }

    public static MongoDecimal operator *(MongoDecimal value, MongoDecimal value2)
    {
        var right = SafeDecimal(value);
        var left = SafeDecimal(value2);

        return ToMongoDecimal(left.ToDecimal() * right.ToDecimal(), left.SubValueToValue >= right.SubValueToValue ? left.SubValueToValue : right.SubValueToValue);

    }

    public static MongoDecimal operator /(MongoDecimal value, MongoDecimal value2)
    {
        var right = SafeDecimal(value);
        var left = SafeDecimal(value2);

        if (right.Value == 0 && right.SubValue == 0)
            throw new DivideByZeroException();

        return ToMongoDecimal(left.ToDecimal() / right.ToDecimal(), left.SubValueToValue >= right.SubValueToValue ? left.SubValueToValue : right.SubValueToValue);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MongoDecimal value, MongoDecimal value2)
    {
        if (value == null && value2 == null) return true;
        if ((value == null && value2 != null) || (value != null && value2 == null)) return false;

        return value.ToDecimal() == value2.ToDecimal();
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MongoDecimal value, MongoDecimal value2)
    {
        return !(value == value2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this == (obj as MongoDecimal);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = (int)2166136261;
            hash = (hash * 1677619) ^ Value.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 1677619) ^ SubValue.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 1677619) ^ SubValueToValue.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public static MongoDecimal SafeDecimal(MongoDecimal d)
    {
        if (d != null)
            return d;
        return new MongoDecimal { SubValue = 0, Value = 0, SubValueToValue = 1 };

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value) can help you...

Comment: Yea I saw that one too, but it didn't give me any answers. Just more questions :P  I hoped that mongodb would implement it in the core. That would make the aggregation more easy on large sets. I guess it will be slower to have it like a string and parse it.

I'll stick with this one and test it against the string implementation that mongodb has done.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473147/how-to-use-decimal-type-in-mongodb). Maybe [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473147/how-to-use-decimal-type-in-mongodb) can help you.